# LIDAR data for Japan

Tags: japan

Is there any public or private sources of LIDAR data in Japan? Searching online did not lead me to any sources.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what website have you looked for it but here is the list:

https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search?m=25.59375!-135.421875!2!1!0!

https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search?m=25.59375!-135.421875!2!1!0!

http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/datasets?listAll=true   --->   it's not there yet but keep an eye

http://glovis.usgs.gov/  ---> required you to have to run Javascript.

https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/data_access

if it is not what you look or find for a specific of area for Japan, I would recommend that you to contact someone in Japan that might know of for free. You can contact USGS or NASA for more information.

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. I checked these websites before. In this case, I am looking for high resolution data (Lidar or photogrammetric) for free.

Comment: I can find these kind of data in many countries but for Japan I didn't find anything.

Comment: You may need to contact someone in Japan that can help you out.  See if you can reach out to Japan. See the map here http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/ops_map.png